# mbstring Ubuntu 14.04 dependency package conflict

Tags: php, ubuntu, php-7, mbstring

I am trying to install PHP mbstring module in my Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I've used "**sudo apt-get -f install php7.0-mbstring**" to install the module. I've added necessary source list in "**/etc/apt/sources.list**".

When I run the above mbstring installation command I get the following error.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    php7.0-mbstring : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6) but 7.0.21-1~ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 is to be installed
>                      Conflicts: php7.0-mbstring:i386 but 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6 is to be installed
>    php7.0-mbstring:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:33) but it is not installable
>                           Depends: php7.0-common:i386 (= 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6) but it is not going to be installed
>                           Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
>                           Conflicts: php7.0-mbstring but 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6 is to be installed
>   E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

What is the recommended solution here? Do I need to uninstall PHP 7.0 and reinstall or is there any other low risk solution?

**Edit:** I've tried to install with **sudo apt-get -f install** as well. I get the same following error,

> php7.0-mbstring:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:33) but it is not installable
>                           Depends: php7.0-common:i386 (= 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6) but it is not installed
>                           Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
>   E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
>   E: Unable to correct dependencies

Comment: Have you tried as it suggests `sudo apt-get -f install`? (BTW 14.04 was EOL April this year)

Comment: @NigelRen, yes I've tried that too. I get this error when I run sudo apt-get -f install.
 php7.0-mbstring:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:33) but it is not installable
                        Depends: php7.0-common:i386 (= 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies

Comment: As it's complaining about libc6, is it installed (try `sudo apt-get install libc6`)

Comment: @NigelRen, thanks for your reply. I've tried to install libc6 as well. This is error I got -  php7.0-mbstring:i386 : Depends: php-common:i386 (>= 1:33) but it is not installable
                        Depends: php7.0-common:i386 (= 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6) but it is not installed
                        Depends: libc6:i386 (>= 2.4) but it is not installed

Comment: @ThangaPandiyan did you manage to find a solution for this issue? I'm currently having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that your package list is up to date, try:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

After it try install packeage again

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

If it doesn't help try to add php repository to source list, for example you can use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php)

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

Comment: Hello @ashot, thanks for your reply. I've tried your solution too. It didn't work either :(. I've been adding so many source lists from the Internet. I get the same error, which is dependency conflict.

Comment: can you change your php version, I'm not sure that it was problem, but may be)